# Moq not calling method named Finalize

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

OK, I am baffled at this point. Moq is not calling my one method, yet the assert on verify does show it is calling all my other methods that are not parameterless. I have even added the following:

```
.Throws<Exception>()
```

just to see if it would even throw, and still nothing (but adding it to other methods works). I know the object being used is my mock because I added a call that IS being logged immediately after the call that is not.

The method name is `Finalize()`. I doubt the naming of the method is the problem, but I have tried everything else.

Code After simplifying down to simplest solution by making the main method public:

```
  var asyncRecognizerMock = new Mock<AsyncRecognizer>();
  var asyncRecognizerFactoryMock = new Mock<AsyncRecognizerFactory>();
  var trainerMock = new Mock<Trainer>();
  trainerMock.Setup(trainer => trainer.Finalize()).Verifiable();
  var trainerDataRepository = new TrainerDataRepository(asyncRecognizerFactoryMock.Object, asyncRecognizerMock.Object);

  trainerDataRepository.FinalizeTrainer(trainerMock.Object);

  trainerMock.Verify(trainer => trainer.Finalize(), Times.Once());
```

My method is now:

```
public void FinalizeTrainer(Trainer wordTrainer)
{
  wordTrainer.Finalize();
}
```

Also, Moq is 4.0.10827.0 running against .Net 3.5

Comment: Ahem... You might want to show some more code - just stating that Moq doesn't do something you expect, is not really much to work with.

Comment: What code would you like me to post? I know that I am calling it right as the same EXACT code will work if I verify my other methods.

Comment: Well, Moq works well with parameterless methods, I know that for a fact - so you might be missing something. How do you set up Moq, and what are the exact call you are making to the Moq'ed object ?

Comment: @driis I added the basics of the code. Again, GetTrainer is proven to work because if I add a different call and Verify it, it works.

Comment: What is `GetTrainer()`? How does your `ObjectUnderTest` gets the `trainerMock`? What is `recognizerMock`?

Comment: Does your factory.constructIt have several overloads?  If so, confirm that GetTrainer() is calling the factory.constructIt that you have specified in your recognizerMock.Setup.

Comment: Again, I KNOW 100% that `GetTrainer` (which isnt even the real method, just a way to shorten the code) is returning the correct. I have added other method calls, like `trainer.SetDataSource(string)` and THAT works, which is using the same EXACT object. I am beginning to wonder if it is that it is both parameterless AND void. I am going to test that in another project now

Comment: Also, I updated my code to be as bare bones as possible and updated my question to show that...still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your method to something other than `Finalize`. If I copy/paste your code and rename the method, it starts to work fine.

It also generates a [compiler warning CS0465](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02wtfwbt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and should be avoided.

The reason this doesn't work is that `Finalize` is actually sort of a reserved name for the class destructor. If you write this C# code:

```
public class Trainer
{
    ~Trainer()
    {
        int x = 1;
    }
}
```

The compiler actually names the destructor `Finalize()` in the IL code:

```
.method family hidebysig virtual instance void 
        Finalize() cil managed
{
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 x)
  .try
  {
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0002:  stloc.0
    IL_0003:  nop
    IL_0004:  leave.s    IL_000e
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0006:  ldarg.0
    IL_0007:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::Finalize()
    IL_000c:  nop
    IL_000d:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  ret
} // end of method Trainer::Finalize
```

In fact if you try to add both a destructor and a Finalize method:

```
public class Trainer
{
    ~Trainer()
    {
    }

    public virtual Finalize()
    {
    }
}
```

This code will no longer compile, because those 2 methods are the same thing. Tricky, eh? :)

It is also noted in ECMA-335:

> **I I.10.5.2 Instance finalizer**
>
> The behavior of finalizers is specified
>   in Partition I. The finalize method for a particular type is specified
>   by overriding the virtual method Finalize in System.Object.

Comment: I had a theory that was the problem...however, it is a horrible pain to change this name as it is legacy-ish from a C++ interop...which also explains why I didnt get a compiler warning in my code. I will change the title to reflect this and maybe help others later.